# Best way to fit a Gaussian Process surrogate model to an RL Reward function

Tags: reinforcement-learning, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization, surrogate

Is there a way to get an estimate of good scaling parameters (namely mean and variance) for a Gaussian Process kernel serving as a surrogate model to a Reinforcement Learning reward function for optimization? Considering the reward function to be a scalar objective of 3 input variables, each having box constraints i.e. l<sub>1</sub><x<sub>1</sub><u<sub>1</sub>, l<sub>2</sub><x<sub>2</sub><u<sub>2</sub>, l<sub>3</sub><x<sub>3</sub><u<sub>3</sub> and r= f(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,x<sub>3</sub>).
Using the following from sklearn:

```
    kernel = ConstantKernel(1.0) * RBF(1.0)
    gauss_pr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel)
```

Also, is it advisable to use a Gaussian Process as a surrogate or would another method be more beneficial? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.